# get discussion message url

Tags: splistitem, discussion-board, url

I have an own UI for discussion messages. The issue is the Url of the actual SPListItem doesn't help:

```
SPListItem message = //get message
var url = message.Url; //returns "/Lists/forum/hello/2.000"
```

What I want is the url "`http://contoso/Lists/forum/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/Lists/forum/hello&CTID=xxx`"

This is what I get when I go to a discussion thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CTID is the ContentTypeId from the listitem and the rootfolder is ServerUrl from the listitem.

Try this code to see if it gives you the url you want.  You could also dynamically get the viewurl if you desire.

```
var url = "http://contoso/Lists/forum/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=" + message["FileDirRef"] + "&CTID=" + message["ContentTypeId"];
```

Comment: Can I get "http://contoso/Lists/forum/" generically?

Comment: I get ...Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/Lists/forum/hello **/2.000** &CTID=xxx2 And therefore I get 404 error

Comment: thank you very much Steve. You gave me a awesome hint. 

Here is the version that I have tested and it really works:
`var url = message["FileDirRef"] + "?Flat.aspx?RootFolder=" + message["FileDirRef"] + "&CTID=" + message["ContentTypeId"];`

Could you update your code in your answer?

Comment: Or `var url = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(argument.List.ParentWeb.Site.Url, message["FileDirRef"] + "?Flat.aspx?RootFolder=" + message["FileDirRef"] + "&CTID=" + message["ContentTypeId"]);`

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  Yes you can get it generically.  From the views collection or calling the defaultviewurl property of the splist.

Comment: I'm not sure if the code you posted would work, it looks like you have two question marks in there, one of them should be a slash i think.

Comment: a typo. First questionmark shouldn't be there. The solution is to replace ServerUrl with FileDirRef, and &FolderCTID with &CTID.